# Android Camera2 unable to start activity auto record video

Tags: java, android, android-camera2

I'm new to Java and Android. I'm trying to start the recording video without performing a button click. But I'm getting an error.

I'm trying to use the method `startCapture()`, but it fails. What can be wrong?

The error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.media.MediaRecorder.start()' on a null object reference

The Activity:

```
public class CameraActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "CameraAction";

    private static final int REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION_RESULT = 0;
    private static final int REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PERMISSION_RESULT = 1;
    private static final int STATE_PREVIEW = 0;
    private static final int STATE_WAIT_LOCK = 1;
    private int mCaptureState = STATE_PREVIEW;

    private TextureView mTextureView;
    private TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener mSurfaceTextureListener = new TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {
            setupCamera(width, height);
            connectCamera();
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture surface) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture surface) {

        }
    };

    private CameraDevice mCameraDevice;

    private CameraDevice.StateCallback mCameraDeviceStateCallback = new CameraDevice.StateCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onOpened(CameraDevice camera) {
            mCameraDevice = camera;
            mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
            if(mIsRecording) {
                try {
                    createVideoFileName();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                startRecord();
                mMediaRecorder.start();
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        mChronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                        mChronometer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        mChronometer.start();
                    }
                });
            } else {
                startPreview();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onDisconnected(CameraDevice camera) {
            camera.close();
            mCameraDevice = null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(CameraDevice camera, int error) {
            camera.close();
            mCameraDevice = null;
        }
    };
    private HandlerThread mBackgroundHandlerThread;
    private Handler mBackgroundHandler;
    private String mCameraId;
    private Size mPreviewSize;
    private Size mVideoSize;

    private MediaRecorder mMediaRecorder;
    private Chronometer mChronometer;
    private int mTotalRotation;
    private CameraCaptureSession mPreviewCaptureSession;
    private CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback mPreviewCaptureCallback = new
            CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {

                private void process(CaptureResult captureResult) {
                    switch (mCaptureState) {
                        case STATE_PREVIEW:
                            // Do nothing
                            break;
                        case STATE_WAIT_LOCK:
                            mCaptureState = STATE_PREVIEW;
                            Integer afState = captureResult.get(CaptureResult.CONTROL_AF_STATE);
                            if(afState == CaptureResult.CONTROL_AF_STATE_FOCUSED_LOCKED ||
                                    afState == CaptureResult.CONTROL_AF_STATE_NOT_FOCUSED_LOCKED) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "AF Locked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            }
                            break;
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCaptureCompleted(CameraCaptureSession session, CaptureRequest request, TotalCaptureResult result) {
                    super.onCaptureCompleted(session, request, result);

                    process(result);
                }
            };
    private CameraCaptureSession mRecordCaptureSession;
    private CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback mRecordCaptureCallback = new
            CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {

                private void process(CaptureResult captureResult) {
                    switch (mCaptureState) {
                        case STATE_PREVIEW:
                            // Do nothing
                            break;
                        case STATE_WAIT_LOCK:
                            mCaptureState = STATE_PREVIEW;
                            Integer afState = captureResult.get(CaptureResult.CONTROL_AF_STATE);
                            if(afState == CaptureResult.CONTROL_AF_STATE_FOCUSED_LOCKED ||
                                    afState == CaptureResult.CONTROL_AF_STATE_NOT_FOCUSED_LOCKED) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "AF Locked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            }
                            break;
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCaptureCompleted(CameraCaptureSession session, CaptureRequest request, TotalCaptureResult result) {
                    super.onCaptureCompleted(session, request, result);

                    process(result);
                }
            };
    private CaptureRequest.Builder mCaptureRequestBuilder;

    private Button mRecordButton;
    private boolean mIsRecording = false;
    private boolean mIsTimelapse = false;

    private File mVideoFolder;
    private String mVideoFileName;

    private MainModel mainModel;

    private static SparseIntArray ORIENTATIONS = new SparseIntArray();
    static {
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_0, 0);
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_90, 90);
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_180, 180);
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_270, 270);
    }

    private static class CompareSizeByArea implements Comparator<Size> {

        @Override
        public int compare(Size lhs, Size rhs) {
            return Long.signum( (long)(lhs.getWidth() * lhs.getHeight()) -
                    (long)(rhs.getWidth() * rhs.getHeight()));
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);

        mainModel = (MainModel)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("serialized_data");

        createVideoFolder();

        mChronometer = (Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.chronometer);
        mTextureView = (TextureView) findViewById(R.id.textureView);
        mRecordButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.videoButton);

        mRecordButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mIsRecording || mIsTimelapse) {
                    mChronometer.stop();
                    mChronometer.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    mIsRecording = false;
                    mIsTimelapse = false;

                    // Starting the preview prior to stopping recording which should hopefully
                    // resolve issues being seen in Samsung devices.
                    startPreview();
                    mMediaRecorder.stop();
                    mMediaRecorder.reset();

                    Intent mediaStoreUpdateIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
                    mediaStoreUpdateIntent.setData(Uri.fromFile(new File(mVideoFileName)));
                    sendBroadcast(mediaStoreUpdateIntent);

                    goNext();

                } else {
                    mIsRecording = true;
                    checkWriteStoragePermission();
                }
            }
        });

        /*
        mRecordButton.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                mIsTimelapse =true;
                checkWriteStoragePermission();
                return true;
            }
        });
        */

    }


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        startBackgroundThread();

        if(mTextureView.isAvailable()) {
            setupCamera(mTextureView.getWidth(), mTextureView.getHeight());
            connectCamera();
        } else {
            mTextureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(mSurfaceTextureListener);
        }

        startCapture();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if(requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION_RESULT) {
            if(grantResults[0] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Application will not run without camera services", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            if(grantResults[1] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Application will not have audio on record", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        if(requestCode == REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PERMISSION_RESULT) {
            if(grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                if(mIsRecording || mIsTimelapse) {
                    mIsRecording = true;
                }
                Toast.makeText(this,
                        "Permission successfully granted!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this,
                        "App needs to save video to run", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        closeCamera();

        stopBackgroundThread();

        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocas) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocas);
        View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        if(hasFocas) {
            decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
        }
    }

    private void setupCamera(int width, int height) {
        CameraManager cameraManager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
        try {
            for(String cameraId : cameraManager.getCameraIdList()){
                CameraCharacteristics cameraCharacteristics = cameraManager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);
                if(cameraCharacteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING) ==
                        CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_BACK){
                    continue;
                }
                StreamConfigurationMap map = cameraCharacteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);
                int deviceOrientation = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
                mTotalRotation = sensorToDeviceRotation(cameraCharacteristics, deviceOrientation);
                boolean swapRotation = mTotalRotation == 90 || mTotalRotation == 270;
                int rotatedWidth = width;
                int rotatedHeight = height;
                if(swapRotation) {
                    rotatedWidth = height;
                    rotatedHeight = width;
                }
                mPreviewSize = chooseOptimalSize(map.getOutputSizes(SurfaceTexture.class), rotatedWidth, rotatedHeight);
                mVideoSize = chooseOptimalSize(map.getOutputSizes(MediaRecorder.class), rotatedWidth, rotatedHeight);

                mCameraId = cameraId;
                return;
            }
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void startCapture() {

        mIsRecording = true;
        checkWriteStoragePermission();

    }

    private void connectCamera() {
        CameraManager cameraManager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
        try {
            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA) ==
                        PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    cameraManager.openCamera(mCameraId, mCameraDeviceStateCallback, mBackgroundHandler);
                } else {
                    if(shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {
                        Toast.makeText(this,
                                "Video app required access to camera", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    requestPermissions(new String[] {android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO
                    }, REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION_RESULT);
                }

            } else {
                cameraManager.openCamera(mCameraId, mCameraDeviceStateCallback, mBackgroundHandler);
            }
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void startRecord() {

        try {
            if(mIsRecording) {
                setupMediaRecorder();
            } else if(mIsTimelapse) {
                setupTimelapse();
            }
            SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture = mTextureView.getSurfaceTexture();
            surfaceTexture.setDefaultBufferSize(mPreviewSize.getWidth(), mPreviewSize.getHeight());
            Surface previewSurface = new Surface(surfaceTexture);
            Surface recordSurface = mMediaRecorder.getSurface();
            mCaptureRequestBuilder = mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_RECORD);
            mCaptureRequestBuilder.addTarget(previewSurface);
            mCaptureRequestBuilder.addTarget(recordSurface);

            mCameraDevice.createCaptureSession(Arrays.asList(previewSurface, recordSurface),
                    new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onConfigured(CameraCaptureSession session) {
                            mRecordCaptureSession = session;
                            try {
                                mRecordCaptureSession.setRepeatingRequest(
                                        mCaptureRequestBuilder.build(), null, null
                                );
                            } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onConfigureFailed(CameraCaptureSession session) {
                            //Log.d(TAG, "onConfigureFailed: startRecord");
                        }
                    }, null);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void startPreview() {
        SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture = mTextureView.getSurfaceTexture();
        surfaceTexture.setDefaultBufferSize(mPreviewSize.getWidth(), mPreviewSize.getHeight());
        Surface previewSurface = new Surface(surfaceTexture);

        try {
            mCaptureRequestBuilder = mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);
            mCaptureRequestBuilder.addTarget(previewSurface);

            mCameraDevice.createCaptureSession(Arrays.asList(previewSurface),
                    new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onConfigured(CameraCaptureSession session) {
                            //Log.d(TAG, "onConfigured: startPreview");
                            mPreviewCaptureSession = session;
                            try {
                                mPreviewCaptureSession.setRepeatingRequest(mCaptureRequestBuilder.build(),
                                        null, mBackgroundHandler);
                            } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onConfigureFailed(CameraCaptureSession session) {
                            //Log.d(TAG, "onConfigureFailed: startPreview");

                        }
                    }, null);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void closeCamera() {
        if(mCameraDevice != null) {
            mCameraDevice.close();
            mCameraDevice = null;
        }
        if(mMediaRecorder != null) {
            mMediaRecorder.release();
            mMediaRecorder = null;
        }
    }

    private void startBackgroundThread() {
        mBackgroundHandlerThread = new HandlerThread("Camera2VideoImage");
        mBackgroundHandlerThread.start();
        mBackgroundHandler = new Handler(mBackgroundHandlerThread.getLooper());
    }

    private void stopBackgroundThread() {
        mBackgroundHandlerThread.quitSafely();
        try {
            mBackgroundHandlerThread.join();
            mBackgroundHandlerThread = null;
            mBackgroundHandler = null;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static int sensorToDeviceRotation(CameraCharacteristics cameraCharacteristics, int deviceOrientation) {
        int sensorOrienatation = cameraCharacteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SENSOR_ORIENTATION);
        deviceOrientation = ORIENTATIONS.get(deviceOrientation);
        return (sensorOrienatation + deviceOrientation + 360) % 360;
    }

    private static Size chooseOptimalSize(Size[] choices, int width, int height) {
        List<Size> bigEnough = new ArrayList<Size>();
        for(Size option : choices) {
            if(option.getHeight() == option.getWidth() * height / width &&
                    option.getWidth() >= width && option.getHeight() >= height) {
                bigEnough.add(option);
            }
        }
        if(bigEnough.size() > 0) {
            return Collections.min(bigEnough, new CompareSizeByArea());
        } else {
            return choices[0];
        }
    }

    private void createVideoFolder() {
        File movieFile = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES);
        mVideoFolder = new File(movieFile, "JobConvoVideos");
        if(!mVideoFolder.exists()) {
            mVideoFolder.mkdirs();
        }
    }

    private File createVideoFileName() throws IOException {
        String timestamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String prepend = "VIDEO_" + timestamp + "_";
        File videoFile = File.createTempFile(prepend, ".mp4", mVideoFolder);
        mVideoFileName = videoFile.getAbsolutePath();
        return videoFile;
    }

    private void checkWriteStoragePermission() {
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                try {
                    createVideoFileName();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if(mIsTimelapse || mIsRecording) {
                    startRecord();
                    mMediaRecorder.start();
                    mChronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                    mChronometer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    mChronometer.start();
                }
            } else {
                if(shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "app needs to be able to save videos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PERMISSION_RESULT);
            }
        } else {
            try {
                createVideoFileName();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if(mIsRecording || mIsTimelapse) {
                startRecord();
                mMediaRecorder.start();
                mChronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                mChronometer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mChronometer.start();
            }
        }
    }

    private void setupMediaRecorder() throws IOException {
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.SURFACE);
        mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
        mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(mVideoFileName);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(1000000);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(30);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoSize(mVideoSize.getWidth(), mVideoSize.getHeight());
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
        mMediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
        mMediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(mTotalRotation);
        mMediaRecorder.prepare();
    }

    private void setupTimelapse() throws IOException {
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.SURFACE);
        mMediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_QVGA));
        mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(mVideoFileName);
        mMediaRecorder.setCaptureRate(2);
        mMediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(mTotalRotation);
        mMediaRecorder.prepare();
    }

    private void goNext() {

        mainModel.questions.remove(0);

        if (mainModel.questions.isEmpty())
        {
            //END
            Intent endSuccess = new Intent(this, SuccessActivity.class);
            endSuccess.putExtra("serialized_data", mainModel);
            startActivity(endSuccess);
        }
        else{

            Intent goToInterview = new Intent(this, InterviewActivity.class);
            goToInterview.putExtra("serialized_data", mainModel);
            startActivity(goToInterview);

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was be able to make it by simply adding this line at the end of the onCreate method: mIsRecording = true;

The code

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);

    mainModel = (MainModel)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("serialized_data");

    createVideoFolder();

    mChronometer = (Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.chronometer);
    mTextureView = (TextureView) findViewById(R.id.textureView);
    mRecordButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.videoButton);

    mRecordButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mIsRecording || mIsTimelapse) {
                mChronometer.stop();
                mChronometer.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                mIsRecording = false;
                mIsTimelapse = false;

                // Starting the preview prior to stopping recording which should hopefully
                // resolve issues being seen in Samsung devices.
                startPreview();
                mMediaRecorder.stop();
                mMediaRecorder.reset();

                Intent mediaStoreUpdateIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
                mediaStoreUpdateIntent.setData(Uri.fromFile(new File(mVideoFileName)));
                sendBroadcast(mediaStoreUpdateIntent);

                goNext();

            } else {
                mIsRecording = true;
                checkWriteStoragePermission();
            }
        }
    });
    mIsRecording = true;

}
```